# How to receive Javascript variables in PHP with page transition

Tags: javascript, php, post

I have HTML/Javascript file and PHP file like this.

In "recive.php" how can I print the contents of the variable "Hello World" ?

When the button was clicked, change page to "recive.php" and print "Hello World".

**send.html**

```
<html>
<button id="getbtn">Button</button>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#getbtn').on("click",function(event){
  var string = "HelloWorld"
  console.log(string);
  });        
  });
</script>
</html>
```

**recive.php**

```
<?php 
echo $_POST["string"];
```

Comment: You might consider submitting a [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code. The first one is that apparently you want to use jquery in your `send.html` page, but you're not including it. Either include it or use pure javascript. Improve your code a bit and post it again.

Answer (score 2):

To do so you first need to understand that your jQuery client code run on a client computer and the php may run on a far sever.  So you can't share variables  between the client and the server. You can send an http request to your php server that contain a variable data .

A form with an action attribute is a one way to send a post http request. You can also using fetch to do so.

```
fetch(url, {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a form with hidden elements and catch the posted data on receive.php using $_POST[].

on body of send.html

```
<form action="receive.php" method="POST" id="sendForm" style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" id="passString" name="string" value="hello world">
</form>
<button id="getbtn">Button</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#getbtn').on("click",function(event){
            var exampleText = 'Hello World';
            $('#passString').val(exampleText);
            form = document.getElementById('sendForm').submit();
        });        
    });
</script>
```

now you can get data on $_POST[] on your receive.php

Note: you have to run html file from your localhost to get the form data on receive.php as php is server side scripting language and needs a server running

Comment: Incidentally, a [submit button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit) can submit the form directly without using JavaScript.